# why i can't join instances to the kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm trying to create EKS cluster with one node group and 3-nodes.
In AWS could see that 1 node got attached. However, Node Group status = Create failed and getting the below error:

```
     Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group (eks-cluster-dev:workernodes-dev) to create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: 1 error occurred:
│       * i-06d98434fc92c67b5, i-0a8f71803eca13600: NodeCreationFailure: Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster
│
│
│
│   with module.eks_cluster.aws_eks_node_group.worker-node-group[0],
│   on modules/eks/eks.tf line 87, in resource "aws_eks_node_group" "worker-node-group":
│   87: resource "aws_eks_node_group" "worker-node-group" {
│
╵
```

cat module/eks/eks.tf

```
      resource "aws_eks_cluster" "eks_cluster" {
      count    = var.pubsubnet ? 1 : 0
      name     = format("%s-%s", var.eks_cluster_name, var.env)
      role_arn = var.eks_cluster_role_arn
    
      vpc_config {
        subnet_ids         = var.subnet_ids
        security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]
      }
    
    }
    
    resource "aws_eks_node_group" "worker-node-group" {
      count           = var.pubsubnet ? 1 : 0
      cluster_name    = format("%s-%s", var.eks_cluster_name, var.env)
      node_group_name = "workernodes-${var.env}"
      node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.workernodes.arn
      subnet_ids      = var.subnet_ids
      instance_types  = var.instance_type
    
      scaling_config {
        desired_size = 3
        max_size     = 3
        min_size     = 1
    
      }
    
    }
```

The `pubsubnet` variable is set to `true`.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Uhm, I don't understand. Is it working or not?

Comment: Nope..Not working

Comment: It used to work before i apply the count = var.pubsubnet true or false condition

Comment: Can you try `cluster_name  = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster[0].name`?

Comment: Same error..(count.index also tried)

Comment: It was public route table issue sorted out.....
I can create EKS cluster without any issues.